# DirectMail markers and TemplaVoila

Tags: typo3, templavoila

Is it possible to use markers such as `###USER_name###` with a TemplaVoila template? If this is not possible, is there an alternative?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*(Deleted my question in comment, cause I realized what you want)*

Markers for DirectMail can be placed in TV (they will be not parsed by TV) or even in some content element. They just need to be available in the rendered content before DM will take it for further processing. Preview your page which has to be used as DM template and make sure that there are markers like `###USER_name###` visible (untouched).

Comment: Ok, that should be pretty straightforward. If you have succesfully used the two together, have you been able to send an html email ? I am trying to figure out why the Testmail (no marker replacing) is arriving as multi-part MIME in GMail whereas the Mass Send is showing html in plain text. I see that in the first instance that only the HTML table code is being used whereas the entire HTML code is showing in the second instance.

Comment: I'm pretty sure I did, but must confess, it was long time ago, I don't remember the details. You can additionally try to put your marker to some content element and check if this resolve the problem. Last time when I used DM's markers it was for sure put in CE as client wanted to gain access to the footer's content without need of changing template's file.

Comment: I found out what was causing the issue. I was using website usergroup for the recipient list and there's a directmail setting for each user saying if the newsletter should be activated and whether to receive e-mails as HTML. I'm glad that's finally fixed :)